# R: rolling frequency

Tags: r, frequency

Hi I have to account the rolling frequency.

better explain:

i have a data frame like this

```
Date         ID    IDC    
30/12/2015   A      D
30/10/2015   A      E
30/9/2015    A      D
30/7/2015    A      F
30/6/2016    A      F
30/12/2015   B      G
30/10/2015   B      D
30/9/2015    B      G
30/7/2015    B      E
30/6/2016    B      G
```

i have to account the rolling frequency IDC (3 month) by ID

The final Data frame should be:

```
Date         ID    IDC    Freq
30/12/2015   A      D      2
30/12/2015   A      E      1
30/10/2015   A      E      1
30/10/2015   A      D      1
30/10/2015   A      F      1
30/9/2015    A      D      1
30/9/2015    A      F      1
...    
30/12/2015   B      G      2
30/12/2015   B      D      1
30/10/2015   B      D      1
30/10/2015   B      D      1
30/10/2015   B      E      1
30/9/2015    B      G      2
30/9/2015    B      E      1
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package and  assuming df is your dataframe:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, freq:= .N, by = c("ID","IDC")]
```